# Adapter Delegate library with PagingData

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there any Adapter Delegate library, that supports Paging Data?

I tried this library:
https://github.com/sockeqwe/AdapterDelegates

But it supports only PagedList, which is deprecated:

Pagination
There is an additional artifact for the pagination library:

implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann:adapterdelegates4-pagination:4.3.2'
Use PagedListDelegationAdapter.